# Split pyspark dataframe column and limit the splits

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the below spark dataframe.

```
Column_1
Physics=99;name=Xxxx;age=15
Physics=97;chemistry=85;name=yyyy;age=14
Physics=97;chemistry=85;maths=65;name=zzzz;age=14
```

I have to split the above dataframe column into multiple columns like below.

```
column_1                         name   age
Physics=99                       Xxxx         15
Physics=97;chemistry=85          yyyy           14
Physics=97;chemistry=85;maths=65 zzzz      14
```

I tried split using delimiter ; and limit. But it splits the subjects too into different columns. Name and age is clubbed together into single column. I require all subjects in one column and only name and age in separate columns.

Is it possible to achieve this in Pyspark.

Comment: As array or string?

Comment: I would require it as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace trick to split the columns.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Physics=99;name=Xxxx;age=15'),('Physics=97;chemistry=85;name=yyyy;age=14'),('Physics=97;chemistry=85;maths=65;name=zzzz;age=14')], 'string').toDF('c1')

df.withColumn('c1', f.regexp_replace('c1', ';name', ',name')) \
  .withColumn('c1', f.regexp_replace('c1', ';age', ',age')) \
  .withColumn('c1', f.split('c1', ',')) \
  .select(
    f.col('c1')[0].alias('stat'),
    f.col('c1')[1].alias('name'),
    f.col('c1')[2].alias('age')) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------+---------+------+
|stat                            |name     |age   |
+--------------------------------+---------+------+
|Physics=99                      |name=Xxxx|age=15|
|Physics=97;chemistry=85         |name=yyyy|age=14|
|Physics=97;chemistry=85;maths=65|name=zzzz|age=14|
+--------------------------------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this to extract the names with a regex:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Physics=99;name=Xxxx;age=15",), ("Physics=97;chemistry=85;name=yyyy;age=14",),("Physics=97;chemistry=85;maths=65;name=zzzz;age=14",)], ["Column1"])
new_df = df.withColumn("name", F.regexp_extract('Column1', r'name=(\w+)', 1).alias('name'))
new_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+----+
|             Column1|name|
+--------------------+----+
|Physics=99;name=X...|Xxxx|
|Physics=97;chemis...|yyyy|
|Physics=97;chemis...|zzzz|
+--------------------+----+
```